# create-react-app with node express getting %PUBLIC_URL%

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I'am trying create-react-app with express server. after setting server when I hit request I'm getting

`GET http://localhost:3333/%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico 400 (Bad Request)`

On error preview its giving me

```
URIError: Failed to decode param '/%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico'
    at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
    at decode_param (/home/owaishanif/code/flashcard-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:172:12)
    at Layer.match (/home/owaishanif/code/flashcard-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:123:27)
    at matchLayer (/home/owaishanif/code/flashcard-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:574:18)
    at next (/home/owaishanif/code/flashcard-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:220:15)
    at jsonParser (/home/owaishanif/code/flashcard-app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:103:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/owaishanif/code/flashcard-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/owaishanif/code/flashcard-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/owaishanif/code/flashcard-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/owaishanif/code/flashcard-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

---

Here is the Server Code

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require ('path');

var data = {};

express()
    .use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'public')))
    .use(bodyParser.json())

    .get('/api/data', (req, res) => res.json(data))

    .post('/api/data', (req, res) => res.json(data = req.body))

    .get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile( path.resolve( __dirname, '..', 'public/index.html')))

    .listen(3333, function(){
        console.log('server running at 3333');
    });
```

I want to use create react app with server. There are articles online but they are outdated. Help tips and tricks are welcome.

Comment: Can you post your front-end code I think problem from fron-end

Comment: @Burdy I am not the question author so I cannot post the front-end. Locally I have a simplest one - just default page noting more.

Comment: I have solved this using create-react-app build which creates a build folder. and other files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solved this using `create-react-app` `build` which creates a build folder. also `%public_url%` string is replaced by some yarn scripts behind the scenes. So we cant directly serve that folder. Instead we have to generate using `build`.

Use `yarn build` or `npm run build`. That will generate a build folder containing `asset`, `manifest`, and other files.

After that, use that build folder to statically serve your files for production use.

Comment: That's right. Server should return files from the dist folder generated after you run `npm run build`.